# Convert a get a character's unicode(?) value?

Tags: c#, unicode, converters

I need to convert a char to an int and back.

Here's what I'm using to convert the char to an int:

```
(char)65 // Returns 'a'
```

Here's what I'm TRYING to use to convert it back:

```
(int)'a' // Returns 97
```

Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: `(char)65` should return `'A'` not `'a'`, http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Why do you need this conversion? Most times you're better off using Encoding to encode/decode from specific encoding to another without having to know (or worry) about the native encoding used by the CLR.

Answer (score 7):

try this,

```
char x = 'a';
int y = (int)x;
```

Comment: `a = 97`, while `A = 65`

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I messed it up like that. Whoops, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

65 is the character code for a capital 'A'. 97 is a lower case 'a'.